# Anyway to execute logic after chunk but before commit

Tags: spring-batch

In Spring Batch, what is the proper way to perform some kind of logic after the chunk logic is done, but *before* commit/rollback?

`afterChunk` is currently triggered after transaction.  What if I want to do some kind of cleanup before commit? (e.g. cleanup some temp records inserted in `beforeChunk`).

One workaround I can think of is by making use a CompositeWriter, and have the extra logic being another writer.  However it is going to make maintenance difficult, because I cannot make up a shared parent step configuration that contains that "extra logic".

Comment: The question that should be asked is, if that cleanup fails, should you still roll back everything?  In your example, you mention the idea of cleaning up temp records inserted in beforeChunk.  If that cleanup fails, do you want to have to re-run all the processing in that chunk?  By doing it before the commit/rollback, you'd have to redo all the work because your cleanup wasn't successful (which may not be ideal).

Comment: In fact that's not really my concern.  I just want something to be setup and cleaned up within my transaction, that's it.  I know the implication of having the action done inside or outside of txn.  There can be a lot of reason apart from "rolling back the chunk or not".  For example, I may simply don't want my temp data in beforeChunk visible by other transactions, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ItemWriteListener.afterWrite()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemWriteListener.html#afterWrite)

> Called after ItemWriter.write(java.util.List) This will be called
>   before any transaction is committed, and before
>   ChunkListener.afterChunk(ChunkContext)

Comment: I can't imagine I missed that, thanks so much.  (I believe that's something not available in Spring Batch 1.0, coz design for writer is different at that time.  I simply haven't pay enough attention on the changes of Spring Batch afterwards  :P  )